# IdentityServer4 cookie in uninteractive flow

Tags: cookies, identityserver4

Every time I use Identity Server 4 to log in from a related client and the flow is interactive (the user is prompted to the login page) I get the cookies `idsrv` and `idsrv.session` (after a successfull login of course) but the same cookies are not there when the flow is uninteractive (there is no login page) but successfull.

Is this a standard behavior for Identity Server 4? Is it possible to have it to generate these cookies for uninteractive flow as well?

In the docs I see there is a way to customize Cookie settings but I can keep the default implemetation, I would like to just have these cookies also for uninteractive flow.

EDIT: I need this because I'm implementing a custom grant where a client send me a JWT token. I need to translate this token and generate a valid IS4 access token for the user I got from the client JWT. The problem is that this is basically a flow where usually you get prompted to the login page of IS4 to enter your credential but I am skipping this part since I get all info I need to auth a user form the JWT token of the client. I need the cookies to be setted like it happens in every standard interactive flow. Coookies are not getting setted when the flow is between two clients.

Comment: Can you expand on what you mean by "uninteractive flow" please? Also, where are you trying to access the cookies from?

Comment: With uninteractive flow I mean getting an access token without any login page in the middle like standard flow AuthCode and ResourceOwnerPassword. The grant I'm using is custom and it's initiated by a client but at the end I need to authenticate a user. I need to be able to add cookies also for this flow

Comment: Anything using the authorize endpoint via the browser should include those cookies, if they weren't included then it would automatically redirect to your sign in UI. ResourceOwnerPassword shouldn't really be used but also doesn't require the cookies because you're providing the credentials in the call anyway.

Comment: Yes, this is the matter. The custom flow I designed receive a JWT token in input. I convert this token to an IS4 Access Token. When the user is redirected to the target Angular App it doesn't see the cookie of IS4 even if I actually generated a token for a user. As a result, the app wants me to login and redirect me to IS4 again ... basically I'm saying that the custom grant is not generating idsrv and idsrv.session cookies like it happens when the user log in directly from IS4

Comment: That is what I’d expect, if using a custom grant type why is the client redirecting at all?

Comment: Ok, so IS4 generates cookies only when the flow require user interaction? Because when I test my grant in Postman and capture cookies they are acttualy generated but when I test the flow from browser It's not working like expected

Comment: As in you're setting cookies within the token endpoint extension grant handler?

Comment: I tried to set cookies in the extension grant implementation just to see if it was working (I used ```SignInAsync``` from the context of ```IHttpContextAccessor```), still the client is not lettig me in without another login and also from the home page of OIDC It says I'm not loggend in. How is this custom grant supposed to be used then? Do I have to let the client handle the access_token in the response on his own?